# How to use add_annotations in a bar chart

Tags: r, text, graph, bar-chart, plotly

I need help to add some notes on a chart bar, built with `plotly`.

I have the following data frame "*s*":

```
s_0 <- c("NH", "OR", "NE", "PA", "NJ", "MA", "IL", "CA", "WI", "OH", "WV")
s_1 <- c(0.66719, 0.62480, 0.62797, 0.55121, 0.25582, 0.63407, 0.57009, 0.29712, 0.19979, 0.08913, -0.16944)
s <- data.frame(s_0, s_1)
```

I use `plot_ly()` to produce the following bar chart:

```
s_plot <- plot_ly(x = ~s_1, y = reorder(s_0, s_1),
type = 'bar',
orientation = 'h',
marker = list(color = 'rgba(50, 50, 100, 1)',
line = list(color = 'rgba(128, 0, 128)')))
```

[image: bar chart]

I want to add the values of "s_1" in the graph at the end of the bars, like in the image below but for every bar.

[image]

I suppose I had to use `add_annotations()`, but I don't know how to do it.

I gently ask for the code, I know it should be very simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modification of your code and the [example](https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/#styled-bar-chart-with-direct-labels) provided by Plotly gives almost the right layout.

Usually the annotation would be half way in the bar, setting the `xanchor` to `left` fixes that problem, but then your negative value is hard to see.

Suggested solution:

```
xanchor = ifelse(s_1 > 0, 'left', 'right')
```

[image]

```
library(plotly)

s_0 <- c("NH", "OR", "NE", "PA", "NJ", "MA", "IL", "CA", "WI", "OH", "WV")
s_1 <- c(0.66719, 0.62480, 0.62797, 0.55121, 0.25582, 0.63407, 0.57009, 0.29712, 0.19979, 0.08913, -0.16944)
s <- data.frame(s_0, s_1)

s_plot <- plot_ly(x = ~s_1, y = reorder(s_0, s_1),
                  type = 'bar',
                  orientation = 'h',
                  marker = list(color = 'rgba(50, 50, 100, 1)',
                                line = list(color = 'rgba(128, 0, 128)')))  %>%
  layout(annotations = list(x = s_1, y = reorder(s_0, s_1), text = s_1, xanchor = ifelse(s_1 > 0, 'left', 'right'),
                             yanchor = 'center',
                            showarrow = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use:

```
add_text(s_plot, text = s_1, marker = NULL, textposition = 'right')
```

You may want to play with different attributes:

> Valid attributes include:
>
> 'type', 'visible', 'showlegend', 'legendgroup', 'opacity', 'name',
>   'uid', 'hoverinfo', 'stream', 'x', 'x0', 'dx', 'y', 'y0', 'dy',
>   'text', 'mode', 'hoveron', 'line', 'connectgaps', 'fill', 'fillcolor',
>   'marker', 'textposition', 'textfont', 'r', 't', 'error_y', 'error_x',
>   'xaxis', 'yaxis', 'xsrc', 'ysrc', 'textsrc', 'textpositionsrc',
>   'rsrc', 'tsrc', 'key'

Comment: It actually adds the text, however it completely miss the correct position. Do you know how to fix that?